# Galera replication ignore table

Tags: mariadb, database-replication, galera, database-cluster

With normal Mysql replication we can ignore tables with: replicate_ignore_table

I can't find any information on whether or not it's possible to do this with Galera cluster replication.

I'd like to ignore a table that is not important so that no cluster wide locks have to be acquired when performing an action on the database.

Comment: have you found the answer?? I've got the same issue here

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to make the table MyISAM or MEMORY.

Answer (score 0):

For ignore a table that is not important, convert this like MyISAM and the galera cluster ignore this automaticaly.